# Laravel 4 - Redirect::route with parameters

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to specify a Redirect::route to a Resource Controller with parameters and specify how the parameters are handled?

I have the following route defined:

`Route::resource('account','AccountController');`

In another route I want to be able to pass parameters to account.create with values acquired earlier so I can pre-populate the create form, but want them passed using as a POST request.

`Redirect::route('account.create',array('name' => $name));`

The above works, but passes the parameters as a GET request.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
Redirect::route('account.create')->with('name', $name);
```

This'll flash it to the session, which you would then retrieve after the redirect with `Session::get('name')`.

Comment: I'm trying this solution but the variable is not passed to my view. I think it has something to do with the way I define the route in routes.php: Route::get('login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogin'));

How do you define yours?

Comment: @BjörnAndersson - The `with` method called on the redirect does not pass anything into the view. All it does is flash the data to the session, so that you can retrieve it with `Session::get()`.

Comment: Isn't that a contradiction to what the docs say about passing data into views here: http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views ?

Comment: @BjörnAndersson - The `with` method that you call on the view and the `with` method that you call on a redirect are 2 separate methods that share nothing besides for their name.

Comment: You can then retrieve you passed variable so $name = Session::get('name');

Answer (score 0):

Another extra info

You can't (o should not?) use dots in config session cookie's var. I had thoubles with this before. If you are having issues with this go check this value.

Refer to [this link](http://harrybailey.com/2009/04/dots-arent-allowed-in-php-cookie-names/) for more information.