# Laravel 4 - Redirect with flash message not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In my Laravel 4 project, I am trying to set a flash message when redirecting, like so:

```
return Redirect::route('main')->with('flash', 'Message here.');
```

(I looked at the following: [Laravel 4 - Redirect::route with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727693/laravel-4-redirectroute-with-parameters)).

The redirect happens properly.  In my 'main' view I've got this code to display the flash message:

```
@if (Session::has('flash'))
  <div class="flash alert">
    <p>{{ Session::get('flash') }}</p>
  </div>
@endif
```

But it doesn't work: `Session::get('flash')` returns an array, not a string. If I insert a call to `var_dump(Session::get('flash'))`, I get this output:

```
array (size=2)
  'new' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'old' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'flash' (length=5)
```

What is happening?  It seems like fairly straightforward code...

Comment: Just do a `var_dump(Session::all());` in your view, and you'll notice that there's already a key named `flash`. Which is an array having a `old` and `new` index. So, use a different key/name for your flash messages.

Comment: Did you try another name for the key instead of *flash* ?

Comment: Thank you, guys, that's exactly what it was!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you redirect with data, the data you save will be 'flashed' into session (meaning it will only be available during the next request, see: http://laravel.com/docs/session#flash-data).

I would be wary of using `'flash'` as a flash data key, as Laravel stores its flash data in a key already with a name of `'flash'`.  Try changing your name to something else.  You may be confusing Laravel's `Session::get` as to where it should be attempting to load the data from.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what it was.  Sorry I can't upvote you, don't have enough reputation for it yet  :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside of the routes.php file try to create your routes within the

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

Route::get('/', [
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'PagesController@home'
]);

Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController');
```

});

And After that use.

```
@if (Session::has('flash'))
    <div class="flash alert">
        <p>{{ Session::get('flash') }}</p>
    </div>
@endif
```

Where you need to access session